# what are those files with "~" in java projects?

Tags: java

I've never seen that,internally generated?How does it work?

Can check what I meen here:
http://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12401970/nutch_0.9_OR.patch

search "java~"

and you can see "java.old" there,what's that again?

Comment: What editor are you using? That kind of file is usually an editor-created backup (whenever you save a file, the editor renames the old version).

Comment: That's probably a backup file from your editor. It has nothing to do with Java in general.

Comment: I've updated,can go and search will get it

Answer (score 6):

It's probably some cruft leftover from emacs.  With emacs, whenever you save a file, it saves a backup of the previous version of the file, and the backup is named with the original filename with a tilde appended to it.  If this is the case (which you can easily verify by comparing `file` with `file~`), then you can safely ignore all of the files named with tildes.

Comment: ...also vi leaves those files

Comment: But it's included in a patch,how come?

Comment: Like he said, its cruft.  It was added to the repository by mistake because whoever made the patch didn't exclude those files.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure its generated from some java process?  ~ in files typically means a temporary file created by editors, such as vim when you modify something.

Comment: it looks like they just accidentally left the temporary file in there, and when the patch notes were released, they did a diff on all files to find changes and showed up in there as well.  Notice that it had both a Query.java and a Query.java~ and the diff for those two are exactly the same.

Comment: and you can see "java.old" there,what's that again?

Comment: same with .old, NutchAnalysis.java and NutchAnalysis.java.old, just a different form of backup with another text editor instead of ~.  They should have removed them from the patch but they didn't, not a big deal.  Safe to delete those files if you really wanted to.

Comment: Thanks,and what is supposed to happen when I apply that patch?
I tried,but only files under "src.orig/" are modified,with files under "src/" untouched.

Comment: if you look at the file path of the modified files, they are all in src.orig/java/org/apache...  If you renamed your src folder, then you'll have to copy those files over manually.  You can safely ignore the ~ and .old files though.

Comment: but --- means old file,+++ means new ones,why only old files are modified?